# Define variable from variable in the .env environment file with Dockerfile

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I can use `--env-file /path/to/.env` to define variables. Is there a way to define variable from previously defined variable in the same file? Example:

```sh
SOME_USER=good_user
ROOT_USER=$SOME_USER
```

Comment: Yes, your example will work exactly as written. `${SOME_USER}` also works.

Comment: the output I'm getting is `$SOME_USER` and `${SOME_USER}`

Comment: Ok. It works for the `.env` file used with docker-compose. Even when passing said file to the container using `env_file` in your `docker-compose.yml` file. I assumed it would work the same way here. Apparently not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, it's only a simple list of values, nothing special such as templating or expansion and it's even broken for quotes so e.g. `VAR="test"` will be actually a value of `"test"` instead of `test`.

The [documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/run/#set-environment-variables--e---env---env-file) also doesn't mention anything, or at least explicitly.

> ... simple (non-array) environment variables ...

> ... This file should use the syntax <variable>=value (which sets the variable to the given value) or <variable> (which takes the value from the local environment), and # for comments. ...

```
$ cat file.env 
VAR=one
VAR2=$VAR
VAR3=${VAR}

$ docker run -it --env-file file.env busybox env | grep VAR
VAR=one
VAR2=$VAR
VAR3=${VAR}
```